# How to disable escape for Django model field's value in template when rendering fields manually

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

I am working on one of my colleague's Django (Django 2.1.4) projects. I spent a couple of days to try to figure out how to disable auto escape for Form field's value when rendering it manually in a template.  `{% autoescape off %} and {{form1.LastName | safe }}` all don't work.

Here are some relative codes.

Form.py

```
class tblstudentinfomodelform_page1(forms.ModelForm):
    LastName = forms.CharField(max_length=30, required=True)
```

views.py

```
def application(request,application_num)
   form1 = tblstudentinfo.objects.get(ApplicationNumber=application_num)
   ...
   form1_forms = tblstudentinfomodelform_page1(initial=form1.__dict__) if form1 else tblstudentinfomodelform_page1(initial=form1)
   ...
   return render(request,'appinfo.html',{'form1':form1_forms})
```

appinfo.html

```
<th>{{form1.LastName}}<br>{{form1.LastName.errors}} {{form1.LastName.value}} </th>
```

Some tests here:

LastName's value is `&#350;haha`

**test1**: add `{% autoescape off %}` at the top of the template and `{% endautoescape %}` at the bottom

**result1**: `{{form1.LastName.value}}` displays correctly -- Şhaha, but input textbox shows `&#350;haha`
[run result -- html page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zf0vq.jpg)

**test2**: delete autoescape tag and add `safe` filter

```
<th>{{form1.LastName | safe}}<br>{{form1.LastName.errors}} {{form1.LastName.value |safe}} </th>
```

**result2**: get the same result, looks like that `safe` filter only worked on form.field.value

Any suggestion?

Thank you.

Comment: The `safe` filter works only when you are trying to have a variable containing html code, which you say is safe to be executed as html. For input values, you will need to do a html unescape in the backend. Check - https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape

Comment: @AswinMurugesh, great, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Add the answer to here in case someone gets the same problem.

Create a function to unescape all HTML entities.

```
from html import unescape
def html_unescape(data_model):  # convert to unicode characters 
# Convert all named and numeric character references (e.g. &gt;, &#62;, &#x3e;) in the string s to the corresponding Unicode characters. 
    for f in data_model._meta.get_fields():
        if ( f.get_internal_type() == "CharField" or f.get_internal_type() == "TextField") and getattr(data_model, f.name):
            #some old records haved escaped many times
            str = unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(unescape(getattr(data_model, f.name))))))
            setattr(data_model, f.name, str)
    return data_model
```

and then

```
form1 = tblstudentinfo.objects.get(ApplicationNumber=application_num)
form1 = html_unescape(form1)
```